# Convert c# regex to javascript regex

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

The following regular expression is workable using C# reg ex:

> `^(?<survey>#_surveyForm.+)|#(?:(?<url>http.+\.\w{3,4}).+_surveyForm=\w+)$`

It matches string such as:

```
#http://localhost/tableaux-p145717.htm=&_surveyForm=second
```

or

```
#_surveyForm=second
```

I used named capturing groups.

I know Javascript doesn't take advantage of named capturing groups (instead it uses \1, \2, etc.). Besides the syntax is slightly different from the one above.

How can I make that reg ex javascript-compliant?

Thanks in advance,

R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, JavaScript doesn't support named captures. You have to change those into "normal" capturing groups and refer to them by number instead of by name:

```
/^(#_surveyForm.+)|#(?:(http.+\.\w{3,4}).+_surveyForm=\w+)$/
```

You should also be aware that `\w` only matches ASCII alphanumerics in JavaScript whereas it matches Unicode alnums in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
/^#(http.+.\w{3,4}.+)?_surveyForm=(\w+)$/
```

Your URL will be in first capturing group, and the survey in the second.

This expression would probably work better for you:

```
/^#(https?:\/\/\S*)?\b_surveyForm=(\w+)$/
```